# Observe a private beta in StackAuth

Tags: discussion, stackauth

[See here.](http://stackauth.com/0.9/sites)

[WebApps](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications) and Meta.WebApps are listed, as WebApps has entered the private beta phase.

Note that the `state` property for those two are `private_beta` and `linked_meta` respectively, values nobody has presumably seen before (except in the docs).

Remember, a `linked_meta` site is implicitly in the same state as its parent site.

---

Also note that the `site_url` and `name` for both are temporary, assuming WebApps graduates to a full site.  When/If such a graduation occurs, webapps.stackexchange.com will be moved to the `aliases` array (which has been [documented for awhile](http://stackauth.com/0.9/help/method?method=sites), but has not been in use).

If you are caching objects with respect to their site, be sure to check `aliases` in addition to `site_url` when doing a lookup.

Comment: `icon_url` is 404ing -- is this going to be added during the beta? I wasnt sure if "pick the icon" is part of the Area51 stuff or if it was decided when the site launches.

Comment: @swanson - there will be a placeholder, eventually.  It will change when/if the site goes public.

Comment: I think I'll sit this out 'till it gets to public beta :)

Comment: @George - access to WebApps is restricted, the point is to see how such a site behaves in the API.  Consider, if your app linked to questions automatically; you'd probably want to handle that differently for a site in private beta since such links probably won't work for most of your users.  Caching content from private beta sites is another area you might want to treat differently.  The list goes on.

Comment: Point taken. What I meant was that I won't add the site to any of my production apps 'till it's out of private beta.

Comment: @George - most [app]s should be grabbing sites (occasionally!) from stackauth.  Being as there was no site in the private beta phase, proper testing of this condition was impossible.  This post is meant to call attention to this opportunity, as it will probably be the only time it happens during the API beta.